# 15.04 upgrade problem

Tags: upgrade, 15.04

When I try to upgrade, the system asks for authentication. I put in my password, which I am sure is right, but the system rejects it. I have tried start with a cap, no cap, two variations, no response.

Comment: Have you changed your password recently?

Comment: Sometimes when you change your password (depending on how you do it) it may not change everywhere.  Try an old password.

Comment: If that doesn't work...what procedure are you using to upgrade?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem...
I installed version 16.04 LTS over the broken install using a USB install flash drive.
I used the exact password of the previous version in the set-up.
16.04 LTS found the 15.10 version and asked if I would like to upgrade.

I clicked YES!

Success.
Jon.